# How do I stop JSDuck generated documentation class names from overlapping

Tags: extjs, jsduck

I am using JSDuck to document the JS classes in my extjs mvc project however on the main page of the API documentation all the names of the classes that are documented overlap each other as the class names are quite long. Whilst I realise that reducing the length of the class names would be a good solution this is not viable.

Please see the issue below

[image: two muppets]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've filed a bug for this: https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/issues/549

At least the column widths should be improved. Maybe also wrap the class names.

You can tweak the styles personally through JSDuck `--css` option.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't initially realise who had replied, definitely appreciate the support and quick response. (For those who don't realise this poster is one of the main contributors to the JSDuck project)

Comment: Feedback on the bug gave us a good temporary workaround https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/issues/549